# How to get jqgrid dot notation data back to server in spring3 mvc in inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display jqgrid with dot notation data and should do inline editing. Where i am able to display the jqgrid data with dot notation and able to do the inline editing also. To save the inline editing, I should get the nested objects back to server. But, it is not returning the nested objects. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

JSON Data:

```
{
    "auditSchedule": null,
    "jqFlexResponse": {
        "page": 1,
        "rpage": null,
        "sortIndex": null,
        "sortOrder": "ASC",
        "searchColumn": null,
        "searchQuery": null,
        "totalPages": null,
        "total": 6,
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": 1217,
                "checklistItem": {
                    "id": 78,
                    "code": "19",
                    "clause": "Information Security Policy Document"
                },
                "remark": "sdf",
                "reportedStatus": "PARTIALLY_COMPLETE",
                "recordInfo": {
                    "createdBy": "ebudaru",
                    "createdDate": 1407578162000,
                    "modifiedBy": "ebudaru",
                    "modifiedDate": 1407649750000
                },
                "auditSchedule": {
                    "id": 280,
                    "afrsubmitDate": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1218,
                "checklistItem": {
                    "id": 78,
                    "code": "19",
                    "clause": "Information Security Policy Document"
                },
                "remark": "hello",
                "reportedStatus": "COMPLETE",
                "recordInfo": {
                    "createdBy": "ebudaru",
                    "createdDate": 1407578162000,
                    "modifiedBy": "ebudaru",
                    "modifiedDate": 1407649763000
                },
                "auditSchedule": {
                    "id": 280,
                    "afrsubmitDate": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

JQGrid setup:

```
colNames: ["Id", "checklist Id","code","clause", "Reported Status","Remark",
                   "AuditSchedule Id",
                    "status", "recordInfo","createdBy","createdDate"],

                   colModel: [

                           { name: "id", width: 25 },
                       { name: "checklistItem.id", width: 25 },
                           { name: "checklistItem.code", width: 25},
                           { name: "checklistItem.clause", width: 25},
                           { name: "reportedStatus", width:150, editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                               editoptions:{ value:{COMPLETE:'COMPLETE', PARTIALLY_COMPLETE:'PARTIALLY_COMPLETE', NOT_COMPLETE:'NOT_COMPLETE'} }},
                           { name: "remark", editable: true, edittype:'text', editoptions: {rows:"3",cols:"20"} },
                           { name: "auditSchedule.id", width: 25 },

                           { name: "status", width: 25 },
                           { name: "recordInfo", width: 25 },
                           { name: "recordInfo.createdBy", width: 25 },
                           { name: "recordInfo.createdDate", width: 120, 
                               formatter: function(cellval, opts){
                                   return $.format.date(cellval, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
                               }, }

        ],
    jsonReader: {
       root: "jqFlexResponse.rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total", 
            repeatitems: false 
            },
        pager: "#auditFindingPager",
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        });

    $("#auditFindingsGrid").jqGrid('editRow', id, 
            { 
                keys : true, 
                url : '../auditFindings/'+id, 
                oneditfunc: function (id){ 

                },
                extraparam:{
                    clause : fetchColValue(id, 'checklistItem.clause'),
                    documentURL:fetchColValue(id,'documentURL'),
                    checklistIdid : fetchColValue(id,"checklistItem.id"),
                    createdBy : fetchColValue(id,'recordInfo.createdBy'),
                    createdDate : fetchColValue(id,'recordInfo.createdDate'),
                    oper: 'UPDATE'
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView editAuditFinding(
            @ModelAttribute("auditFinding") AuditFinding auditFinding
            @RequestParam(value = "oper", required = true) Operation operation,
            HttpSession session) {

logger.info("edit finding Invoked");

}
```

Here, i am getting only auditFinding data..means, id, remark and reportedStatus only. I need to get checklistitem and auditschedule data also. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you checked everything is correct in your jsonReader that has to be the area of trouble. Based on what you have here it looks like the syntax you have is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and viewing the valid jsonReader syntax from jqgrid docs it looks like your jsonReader is not formatted correctly. These are the valid values in jsonReader

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data